# HTML: Making a link, submit in form?

Tags: html

I really want to have a link, such as, "Save" that act the same way as a input type submit button?

I never figured out how to do this, is it even possible? How?

Comment: Does it need to be just HTML, no JavaScript? I'm not sure you can do that. You could style a submit button to look like a standard link though.

Comment: +1.  Doesn't deserve the -1 score just for being a noob.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just style the button to look like a link:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you need to add all the styling to get the same style as your existing links. It's very messy.

Comment: background:none;

Answer (score 2):

its possible using javascript. like this:

```
<form name="theform" ...>
<a href="javascript:document.theForm.submit();">Save</a>
</form>
```

but i would suggest to style a button to look as a link, so you have no problem with clients without javascript

Comment: This is the best answer. Everyone has javascript these days so that shouldn't be a worry. Styling a button to look like a link is messy (requires lots of styling to match existing links). This is the simplest (and therefore best) solution in my opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

Random example:

Form:

`<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="something.php">`

Submit link:
`<a href="javascript:postform()">Click!</a>`

JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function postform( )
{
  document.getElementById('myform').submit() ;
}
</script>
```