# Delete link on richFaces dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, richfaces

I want to be able to delete a user from my DB. The interface has something like the following code, but the `action` method never gets called. What am I missing?

```
        <h:form id="formAdministracionUsuarios">
            <br/>
            <rich:panel style="width: 800px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Administración de usuarios"/>
                </f:facet>

                <rich:dataScroller for="usersTable" fastControls="hide"
                                   boundaryControls="hide" />
                <h:panelGroup/>
                <rich:dataTable id="usersTable" rows="10" var="user"
                                value="#{administrationBean.tablaUsuarios}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <rich:columnGroup>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Nombre"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Usuario"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Dependencia"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Tipo usuario"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Tipo dependencia"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Fecha límite"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Eliminar"/>
                            </rich:column>
                        </rich:columnGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.nombre}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.usuario}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.dependencia}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.correo}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.tipoUsuario}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.tipoDependencia}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.fechaLimiteCarga}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <a4j:commandLink value="Eliminar" execute="@form"
                                         action="#{administrationBean.doEliminarUsuario(user.usuario)}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:dataTable>
                <a4j:outputPanel>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <fieldset>                                
                        <legend>Datos del usuario</legend>
                        <h:panelGrid id="camposUsuario" columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Nombre" for="queryNombre"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Usuario" for="queryUsuario"/>
                            <h:inputText id="queryNombre" required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="Introduzca el nombre." immediate="true"
                                         value="#{administrationBean.queryNombre}">
                                <f:ajax event="keypress" 
                                        listener="#{administrationBean.doClearMessages}"
                                        render="datosUsuario"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                            <h:inputText id="queryUsuario" required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="Introduzca el nombre de usuario."
                                         value="#{administrationBean.queryUsuario}">
                            </h:inputText>                                
                            <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryNombre"/>
                            <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryUsuario"/>

                            <h:outputLabel value="Contraseña:" for="queryContrasena"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Dependencia:" for="queryDependencia"/>
                            <h:inputSecret id="queryContrasena" required="true"
                                           requiredMessage="Introduzca la contraseña."
                                           value="#{administrationBean.queryContrasena}"/>
                            <rich:select id="queryDependencia" required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="Seleccione la dependencia."
                                         defaultLabel="Dependencia..."
                                         value="#{administrationBean.queryDependencia}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{administrationBean.selectDependencia}"/>
                            </rich:select>
                            <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryContrasena"/>
                            <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryDependencia"/>                                

                            <h:outputLabel value="Correo" for="queryCorreo"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Fecha límite:" for="queryFechaLimite"/>
                            <h:inputText id="queryCorreo" required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="Introduzca el correo."
                                         value="#{administrationBean.queryCorreo}"/>
                            <rich:calendar id="queryFechaLimite" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                           value="#{administrationBean.queryFechaLimite}"/>
                            <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryCorreo"/>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                            <a4j:commandButton value="Agregar" execute="@form"
                                               render="datosUsuario usersTable camposUsuario"
                                               action="#{administrationBean.doRegistrarUsuario}"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <a4j:outputPanel id="datosUsuario" style="font-size: 14px; color: #D17100">
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{administrationBean.alreadyRegistered}"
                                          value="Usuario ya existe !"/>
                            <h:outputText rendered="#{administrationBean.registrationComplete}"
                                          value="Usuario registrado !"/>
                        </a4j:outputPanel>
                    </fieldset>
                </a4j:outputPanel>
            </rich:panel>

            <br/>
        </h:form>
```

**UPDATE**
Post the code of the complete form.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is your table part of a form, I think you need to submit the page for any bean actions to be preformed

Comment: nope, I'm no getting errors at all. I actually tried with `actionListener` and `action` but none of them fires the delete method. The table is part of the form.

Comment: Try changing the link to submit the form, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701908/html-making-a-link-submit-in-form and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313478/how-best-to-make-a-link-submit-a-form

Comment: I have updated my question. I've posted all the code... I think I have a clue now that I read the code slowly... maybe because of the validations in the input fields, but how to solve it ?

Comment: u want to call `doEliminarUsuario` function to delete the user right??  and which user u want to delete ?? have u selected any of the user by using the `selection` attribute of the table.. the thing u r trying is having all the users list as parameter and it will nt call d method as parameters are not matching.... so just tell me hw u r deciding which user to delete??????   may be I can help u out.....

Comment: try changing the `<h:form>` to `<a4j:form>`

Comment: @Abhinav: Please try writing like a grown-up. Your childish chat/sms writing style is hard to follow for ones whose native language isn't English.

Comment: @BalusC: ya sure buddy, i will try to follow it up....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.
The whole form includes the `dataTable` stuff and the registration of a new user stuff, i.e. `inputFields`.

What was happening was that when the method in the `h:commandLink` was getting called the action wasn't fired because of the `required` attributes set to true in the `inputFields`.

What I did was to separate in two forms my stuff, first form `dataTable` related stuff and second form `InputFields` stuff

With that I avoid the required attributes in the inputFields and so the `action` method in the `commandLink` now is being called.

Here's what it looks like now:

```
            <h:form id="formUsuariosRegistrados">
                <rich:dataScroller for="usersTable" fastControls="hide"
                                   boundaryControls="hide" />
                <rich:dataTable id="usersTable" rows="10" var="user"
                                value="#{administrationBean.tablaUsuarios}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <rich:columnGroup>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Nombre"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Usuario"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Dependencia"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Tipo usuario"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Tipo dependencia"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Fecha límite"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value=""/>
                            </rich:column>
                        </rich:columnGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.nombre}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.usuario}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.dependencia}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.correo}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.tipoUsuario}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.tipoDependencia}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.fechaLimiteCarga}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <a4j:commandLink value="Eliminar"
                                         render="@form :formFechaLimite :formModificarContrasena"
                                         actionListener="#{administrationBean.doEliminarUsuario(user.usuario)}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:dataTable>
            </h:form>

            <br/>

                <h:form id="formRegistroUsuarios">
                    <a4j:outputPanel>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <fieldset style="width: 350px" >
                            <legend>Datos del usuario</legend>
                            <h:panelGrid id="camposUsuario" columns="2">
                                <h:outputLabel value="Nombre" for="queryNombre"/>
                                <h:outputLabel value="Usuario" for="queryUsuario"/>
                                <h:inputText id="queryNombre" required="true"
                                             requiredMessage="Introduzca el nombre." immediate="true"
                                             value="#{administrationBean.queryNombre}">
                                    <f:ajax event="focus" 
                                            listener="#{administrationBean.doClearMessages}"
                                            render="registroCompletado"/>
                                </h:inputText>
                                <h:inputText id="queryUsuario" required="true"
                                             requiredMessage="Introduzca el nombre de usuario."
                                             value="#{administrationBean.queryUsuario}">
                                </h:inputText>                                
                                <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryNombre"/>
                                <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryUsuario"/>

                                <h:outputLabel value="Contraseña:" for="queryContrasena"/>
                                <h:outputLabel value="Dependencia:" for="queryDependencia"/>
                                <h:inputSecret id="queryContrasena" required="true"
                                               requiredMessage="Introduzca la contraseña."
                                               value="#{administrationBean.queryContrasena}"/>
                                <rich:select id="queryDependencia" required="true"
                                             requiredMessage="Seleccione la dependencia."
                                             defaultLabel="Dependencia..."
                                             value="#{administrationBean.queryDependencia}">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{administrationBean.selectDependencia}"/>
                                </rich:select>
                                <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryContrasena"/>
                                <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryDependencia"/>                                

                                <h:outputLabel value="Correo" for="queryCorreo"/>
                                <h:outputLabel value="Fecha límite:" for="queryFechaLimite"/>
                                <h:inputText id="queryCorreo" required="true"
                                             requiredMessage="Introduzca el correo."
                                             value="#{administrationBean.queryCorreo}"/>
                                <rich:calendar id="queryFechaLimite" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                               value="#{administrationBean.queryFechaLimite}"/>
                                <rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="queryCorreo"/>

                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                                <a4j:commandButton value="Agregar" execute="@form"
                                                   render="registroCompletado :formUsuariosRegistrados camposUsuario :formFechaLimite :formModificarContrasena"
                                                   action="#{administrationBean.doRegistrarUsuario}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <a4j:outputPanel id="registroCompletado" style="font-size: 14px; color: #D17100">
                                <h:outputText rendered="#{administrationBean.alreadyRegistered}"
                                              value="Usuario ya existe !"/>
                                <h:outputText rendered="#{administrationBean.registrationComplete}"
                                              value="Usuario registrado !"/>
                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                        </fieldset>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to delete just one user from the table displayed,, then u have to select one user from there using `selection`.
then in that case -
set your `selection` attribute in table as -

```
selection = "#{bean.selectionTableState}"
```

and declare it in bean as

```
//import for Selection
private Selection selectionTableState;
```

and then in the `action` method use this selection to get the current user.

```
//suppose ClassA is an object class for representing all users in the table, 
//and make sure your **tablaUsuarios** is of that ClassA type.
//so that u can catch one by selection
ClassA classA = this.tablaUsuarios.get(Integer.parseInt(this.selectionTableState.getKeys().next().toString()));
```

This **classA** now has the selected user in it.
u just have to send one of primary value of the user like `userID` to your `DAO` by using sql query to delete the user.
I am sure it will help you ......